# onBlur event post field to php script with Ajax

Tags: ajax, post, onblur

I'm working on lowering shopping cart abandonment rates for a client. I'd like to be able to post form data from individual input fields of a registration form to a php script, every time onblur fires.

The form fields would need to keep the value entered by the visitor and page shouldn't refresh so I think Ajax is the best solution. Any example code that does this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any current codes for work around? We couldn't help you without a starting point.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably work for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sendData(obj) {
                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        // Do stuff when script returns
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET","script.php?" + obj.name + "=" + obj.value + "&t="+Math.random(),true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Input 1 <input type="text" onblur="sendData(this)" name="input1" /><br />
        Input 2 <input type="text" onblur="sendData(this)" name="input2" /><br />
        Input 3 <input type="text" onblur="sendData(this)" name="input3" /><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

The random number at the end of the request is to make sure the browser doesn't return a cached response instead of actually sending your data to the server.